# Django Rest Auth custom reset password confirm url

Tags: django, django-rest-auth, reset-password

With django-rest-framework, when you post a reset password (rest-auth/password/reset/), there is an email send to the user email. This email contains a confirmation URL. I would like to change this url because I'm on a REST app case, I want this email to point on my frontend instead of the django backend.

With the confirmation email case, I had to override `get_email_confirmation_url` method from the `AccountAdapter`. But with the reset password case, I have no clue how to do it (there is no method in the adapter about reseting password).

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it with templatetags:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/

My templatetags file (e.g. `settings_vars.py`):

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_settings_var(name):
    return getattr(settings, name)
```

My variable in my `settings.py`:

```
FRONTEND_URL = 'http://localhost:4200/'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_URL = FRONTEND_URL + 'verify-email/{}'
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM = FRONTEND_URL + 'password-reset/confirm/'
```

Usage in my `password_reset_email.html`:

```
{% load settings_vars %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{% get_settings_var 'ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM' %}?uidb64={{ uid }}&token={{ token }}
{% endblock %}
```

If someone know a better solution feel free to comment.

Hope it can helps someone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945893/django-restauth-custom-password-reset-link check here for working answers

Answer (score 1):

I found that If you are using the dj-rest-auth and you want your reset password link to point to the frontend you can use the following setting

In the settings file.

```py
REST_AUTH = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_USE_SITES_DOMAIN': True,
}
```

Based on https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html