# Django RestAuth Custom password reset link

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have tried the solutions I found for a similar question but none worked for me.

I am using an angular frontend + DRF + Django Rest Auth, for the confirmation url, I was able to override it to point to my frontend by adding a custom adapter that looks liked this,

```
class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def send_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):
        context['activate_url'] = settings.URL_FRONT + \
            'access/verify-email/' + context['key']
        msg = self.render_mail(template_prefix, email, context)
        msg.send()
```

with `URL_FRONT = 'http://localhost:8080/app/#/'` as the setting to direct the user to the client.

My problem is implementing the same thing for the password reset url. I want it to start with the `URL_FRONT` setting and attached the tokens just liked what I have for the confirmation. 
What will be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Where is the reset password showing as of now?

Comment: it shows the url of the django site. So on localhost, it's ```localhost:8000```, I want it to show ```http://localhost:8080/app/#/``` as the url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like django-rest-auth uses `django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm` to handle this:
https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L183

And according to the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetDoneView) you can pass your own email template (note: there was a major change in Django 1.11, so make sure you use your Django version's doc). The default template is `registration/password_reset_form.html`. You can override this by using your own `PasswordResetSerializer` (extending `rest_auth.serializers.PasswordResetSerializer`) in the [django-rest-auth configuration](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).

There you can override the [get_email_options()](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L161) method and set your own template

```
def get_email_options(self):
    return {
        'email_template_name': 'path/to/your/txt_template.html',
        'html_email_template_name': 'path/to/your/html_template.html',
    }
```

Or maybe it's simply enough to pass your URL as `success_url`.

Comment: this works, it was the get_email_options part that I missed when I used a different password serializer

Comment: the answer is very good but when I do it that way for some reason the request is none: / and I don't send any context

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works, but I also used  the frontend url as the site in the admin dashboard and it worked perfectly for all my urls

Comment: Can you explain this further?

Comment: I updated the sites name in the db to the domain of my clients url. For example if the url of the client is `app.example.com`, then update it on your db or create a new site and set your `SITE_ID=2`.

Answer (score -1):

Define these variable in `settings.py`

```
  URL_FRONT = 'http://localhost:8080/app/#/'
  ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_URL = URL_FRONT+ 'verify-email/{}'
  ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM = URL_FRONT+ 'password-reset/confirm/'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me when I tried, I also saw the same answer in a different question

Comment: Downvoted, it's an incomplete copypaste from another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344898/django-rest-auth-custom-reset-password-confirm-url?rq=1